# swift php array to swift json

Tags: php, json, swift

I am trying to work with a swift code to pass vars to php and a response back to swift. this all goes smooth with the following code. This is just a simple peice of code to get things going. It gives me the correct connection and results, how ever i have to pass loads of data which should be in an array i guess. But when i try to send through more data in a array i don't see anything. In php i would explode the results to get them one by one but how do i get loads of values to variables so i can use them again?

below is my code

```
<?php
require('conn.php');
header('Content-type: application/json');
if($_POST) {
    $database =trim ($_POST['database']);
    $engine = trim($_POST['engine']);


    $name = "William";


    $results = Array("name" => $name
                   );



    echo json_encode($results);
}/*end if POST*/

?>
```

this is the swift code

```
let data:NSString = ("bfdprofile" as NSString)
            let engine:NSString = "account" as NSString

            self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as? String




            let url = NSURL(string:"xxxxx.php")
            let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            // set Content-Type in HTTP header
            let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
            let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
            NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

            // set data
            var dataString = "data=\(data)&engine=\(engine)"
            let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

            // set content length
            //NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

            var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
            var error: NSError? = nil
            let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

            if let results = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(reply!, options: nil, error: &error) as? [String: String]{
            if let name = results["name"]{
                labelTestOutput.text = name as? String
                }
            }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it **asynchronously** with `Alamofire` library as simple as that:

```
typealias JSONdic = [String: AnyObject]

let param = ["data": "somedata", "engine": "someEngine"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, URLString: "xxxxx.php", parameters: param).responseJSON() {
    (_,_,json,_) in
    if let json = json as? JSONdic, name = json["name"] as? String {
        // do something with name
    }
}
```

Comment: it a project that is already working so i am not sure how to add it to my project. I have looked into that. I do have swiftyjson installed on my project.  Can i also use that?